# GWT: Adding HTML / Label to flowPanel

Tags: gwt

I would like to use a flowPanel to contain a list of tags.  The tag contain a name and a close button.

However, when I add HTML / Label to flowPanel, it will create a new line because it's a DIV element.

If the HTML / Label is a span element, there is no new line.  However, I can't create spanElement on demand.

Does anyone has any suggestion?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [`InlineLabel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/InlineLabel.html) and/or [`InlineHTML`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/InlineHTML.html) widgets.

Answer (score 1):

set the css style of the Label like this : `display: inline;`